# How to find number months of week including two months

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table that contain num_client, day, week and I want to calculate number of client in each week
Here's some data in the table :

```
num_client,   day,  week
1       01/01/2018     1
2       01/01/2018     1
.
.
.
1       09/01/2018     2
3       10/01/2018     2
.
.
.
.
1       28/01/2018     5
1       01/02/2018     5
2       01/02/2018     5
5       01/02/2018     5
```

. . .
And so on..

I user group by function to do that and everything works fine.
The problem is, when I try to add the month of the week in the aggregation query, there is weeks that are in too separated months,
like the week 5 in year 2018, it includes two months, January and February.

So what I thought of, is to see the number of days : if the week 5 have more days in February than January, then the month for week 5 is February.
And that for every year.
Is their any dynamique function to do this in oracle?

Comment: No there is no function that does this, you would have to write a custom function or query

Comment: I was trying to do that for the last weeks, and I didn't managed to do it, do you have any idea how ?

Comment: I do know how -- I've been studing and working with databases for 25 years.  This website is not for people who want to hire a consultant however, you need to have a question about some work you have done -- people are not just interested in writing it for you.  Show me stuff you have tried in the last weeks and I will tell you why it is not working or help you debug problems.

Comment: I will give you a hint.  The easiest way to solve this problem is to make a table with a row for every day of the year and a column that has the "week number" you want to map to.  Then the "calculation" is simply a join.

Comment: Thanks Hogan, I will try this.

Comment: And for the record, i didnt ask for the whole script or query, I asked for "idea" for a hint, for a simple direction, not the whole thing. Thanks anyway

Comment: Nice -- then you got exactly what you wanted. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way of generating a list of dates and their corresponding week and week-month values, based on the logic you have said (i.e. if the last date in the week is the 1st, 2nd, 3rd or 4th of the month, the week belongs to the previous month):

```
WITH week_months AS (SELECT dt,
                            dt_week_start,
                            dt_week_end,
                            to_number(to_char(dt, 'ww')) week_no,
                            to_number(CASE WHEN TRUNC(dt_week_start, 'mm') != TRUNC(dt_week_end, 'mm') AND to_char(dt_week_end, 'dd') < '05' THEN to_char(dt_week_start, 'mm')
                                           ELSE to_char(dt_week_end, 'mm')
                                      END) mnth
                     FROM   (SELECT to_date('01/01/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') -1 + LEVEL dt,
                                    trunc(to_date('01/01/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') -1 + LEVEL, 'ww') dt_week_start,
                                    trunc(to_date('01/01/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') -1 + LEVEL, 'ww') + 6 dt_week_end
                             FROM   dual
                             CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 400))
SELECT *
FROM   week_months
ORDER BY dt;
```

You could use that dynamically (you'd have to change the inner select in the week_months subquery to pick the dates you're interested in; here I've just picked 400 days from the 1st Jan 2018, but you may need the min/max dates in your table), but depending on how often the query gets run, you may find it better to populate a table and use that to join to your other table(s).

Comment: with a little adjustment to what I actualy am looking for, this worked pretty well, as mentioned above, I created a table that contain this query with little changes, then I did a join from the main table that I want to work with and the table with the query result.
Thank you sir

Comment: Unless you've populated your table from now until the end of time (or at least, Oracle's end-of-time! *{;-) ), you'll need a process to add rows for future dates. Hopefully you've already got that in hand, though

Comment: Yea of course, I changed the condition from <= 400 to <= 4000, so it will be 4000 lines and that's a 10 years, it will be more than enough thouhg